# "Relative dates" are showing future dates for "this" reference

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am trying to get the monday and sunday (first and last day of week respectively, in Costa Rica). So, I did this:

```
    $now = new \DateTime();

    $monday = new \DateTime();
    $monday = $monday->modify("monday this week");

    $sunday = new \DateTime();
    $sunday = $sunday->modify("sunday this week");

    echo "timezone: " . date_default_timezone_get();
    echo "<br>";
    echo "now: " . $now->format('d/m/Y H:i');
    echo "<br>";
    echo "monday: " . $monday->format('d/m/Y H:i');
    echo "<br>";
    echo "sunday: " . $sunday->format('d/m/Y H:i');
```

The output is:

```
timezone: America/Costa_Rica
now: 26/10/2014 19:01
monday: 27/10/2014 00:00
sunday: 02/11/2014 00:00
```

But, how is possible that the currect week is pointing to future dates?

Comment: For some reason referring to "monday this week" and "sunday this week" does not work the way you, and I,  think it would.

Comment: Defining timezome should fix it according to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php): `Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$monday = new DateTime();
// create DateTime object with current time

$monday->setISODate($monday->format('o'), $monday->format('W'));
// set object to Monday this week

$sunday = clone $monday;
// clone DateTime object

$sunday->modify('+6 day');
// add 6 days to Monday, to get the Sunday

echo sprintf(
    'This week is stared on %s, and ended on %s.', 
    $monday->format('Y-m-d'), 
    $sunday->format('Y-m-d')
);
// just print out the result
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/210363)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, your code solve the problem, but I am still investigate why does "this week" return future dates.

Comment: @manix: Like @John said in the comments, this doesn't work like expected. Not 100% sure, but for your first example, where you use `monday this week` you get out 2014-10-27, which IMHO is correct, because weeks in php natively start on Sunday and end on Saturday. And on week between Sunday (2014-10-26) and Saturday (2014-11-01), Monday is on 2014-10-27. This works for all days in the week, but only Sunday is the exception, and this is beyond me. When you use `sunday this week`, and you are currently on Sunday, you will always get next Sunsay, thats why you get 2014-11-02.

Comment: My example is based on [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard, which states: `... beginning with Monday and ending with Sunday`.

Comment: You are right and now I understand the point. Thank you so much @Glavić.